# MySQL divides a column into 2 segments based on the median, and finds the median of each segment？

Tags: mysql, median

Here is my sample table called `t`,Mysql version is 5.7:

```
+----+------+
| id | num  |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    2 |
|  3 |    3 |
|  4 |    4 |
|  5 |    5 |
|  6 |    6 |
|  7 |    7 |
|  8 |    8 |
|  9 |    9 |
+----+------+
```

And I have now found the median is 5,use this sql :

```
SELECT
    AVG( tmp.num ) AS median_val 
FROM
    (
SELECT
    num,
    @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS `row_number`,
    @total_rows := @rownum 
FROM
    t,
    ( SELECT @rownum := 0 ) r 
WHERE
    num IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY
    num
    ) AS tmp 
WHERE
tmp.row_number IN ( FLOOR( ( @total_rows + 1 ) / 2 ), FLOOR( ( @total_rows + 2 ) / 2 ) );
```

But I want to divide the num column into 2 segments based on the median.

first segment is : 1,2,3,4,5; median is:3

second segment is:5,6,7,8,9;  median is:7

I hope the output result:
3,5,7

And here is [online table t](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c2ac8/2)

My idea is to convert the above sql result into @variable, and then make a judgment on the median sub-query condition, but I think it is not very smart.
Thanks